# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence on XATransaction

Tags: oracle, jdbc, transactions, glassfish

On the same data sometimes throws the exception java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence, but in most attempts all working fine.

Java app running on Glassfish 3.1.2.2. Can anybody explain me, where is the problem?

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
@Startup
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)
public class MarketCodesSingleton {

    @Resource(mappedName="jdbc/sss")
    private DataSource source;

    private volatile static Map<Interval, String> marketCodes;

    @PostConstruct
    @Schedule(minute="*/10", hour="*")
    public void fillMarketCodes() {
        try(Connection conn = source.getConnection()) {
            Map<Interval, String> marketCodesInt = new TreeMap<>();
            DaoFactory.getMarketCodesDao().fillMarketCodes(marketCodesInt, conn);
            marketCodes = Collections.unmodifiableMap(marketCodesInt);
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.FINE, "MarketCodes updated");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "fillMarketCodes exception",e);
            throw new EJBException("fillMarketCodes exception",e);
        }
    }

    public String getMarketCode(Long msisdn) {
        Interval interval = new Interval(msisdn);
        return marketCodes.get(interval);
    }

}
```

DaoFactory.getMarketCodesDao().fillMarketCodes:

```
private static final String getMarketCodes_SQL = "CALL SERVICE_PKG.GET_MARKET_CODES(?)";

@Override
public void fillMarketCodes(Map<Interval, String> intervals, Connection conn) throws SQLException {      
    try (CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(getMarketCodes_SQL)) {
        //-10 is a OracleTypes.CURSOR
        cs.registerOutParameter(1, -10);
        cs.execute();
        try (ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(1)) {
            //*******Exception throws on the rs.next() in this method*******
            while (rs.next()) {
                Interval interval = new Interval(rs.getLong("from_no"), rs.getLong("to_no"));
                intervals.put(interval, rs.getString("market_code"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Procedure:

```
  procedure GET_MARKET_CODES(
    c_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  ) AS
  BEGIN
    OPEN c_cursor FOR
      SELECT from_no, to_no, market_code
      FROM market_codes;
  END GET_MARKET_CODES;
```

Connection properties:

```
<jdbc-connection-pool 
    connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="5" 
    datasource-classname="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource" 
    max-pool-size="200" 
    max-connection-usage-count="1000" 
    res-type="javax.sql.XADataSource" 
    steady-pool-size="0" 
    name="sss_pool" 
    connection-creation-retry-attempts="5">
      <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)(PORT = xx)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = xx)))"></property>
      <property name="Password" value="***"></property>
      <property name="User" value="***"></property>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
```

Comment: Could you please post your JDBC connection params?

Comment: Connection params were added

Comment: Try setting KeepXAConnTillTxComplete="true", "Forces the connection pool to reserve a physical database connection and maintain a connection to an application throughout transaction processing, that is, until the distributed transaction is complete." Maybe your problem is caused because the XA transactional context of a connection changes during a result set processing.

Comment: I've also found this advice in the web :) But I'm not sure, that it appropriate for Glassfish. I think, that it only for Weblogic - 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ConsoleHelp/domain_jdbcconnectionpool_config_connections.html#1112241

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very strange, but problem has been solved by removing annotation @ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)

Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 1):

The code is incomplete, so I can only guess:

- the cursor was closed and you tried to fetch again
- you did select for update and committed and then tried to fetch the next row.

Comment: as you can see in method fillMarketCodes cursor was not closed. Exception throws on the rs.next() in this method

as you can see in procedure GET_MARKET_CODES, there is no for update statement

Comment: I'd like to see the definition of getMarketCodes_SQL. In addition I'd highly recommend to turn on sql tracing for the session.

Comment: private static final String getMarketCodes_SQL = "CALL SERVICE_PKG.GET_MARKET_CODES(?)";

Comment: That is not going to work. Do a select service_... from dual.

Comment: Just to add, could you add a null check for the "rs"?
if(rs!=null)
Would help avoiding these exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Is your connection set to auto commit? A fetch across a commit or rollback is likely to cause this exception.

I also noticed that your SQL isn't surrounded by begin/end as in the [Oracle docs](http://www.oradev.com/ref_cursor.jsp) or {} as in this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-cursor-example/) and the [Oracle Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html).

Answer (score 1):

To make certain whether when hitting exception all the rows are processed

Modify the below code to include a counter i to get processed rows and find actual count of rows

```
 int i=0;
  try{
 while (rs.next()) {
            Interval interval = new Interval(rs.getLong("from_no"), rs.getLong("to_no"));
            intervals.put(interval, rs.getString("market_code"));
            i=i+1;
        }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
 Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.FINE, "the total rows processed"+ i);
 Statement stmt = null;
 String query = "select count(1) count_rows                   
               from market_codes";
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    rs1.next();
    String countRows = rs1.getString("count_rows");
    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.FINE,"Actual count of rows"+ countRows);
 }
```